# Me sobrescribe un fichero en JAVA

Tags: java

!Buenas!

Estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba sobre ficheros en Java.

> Trata de ir escribiendo palabras hasta que el usuario introduzca
>   "SALIR". Todo lo que se haya escrito se ha de guardar en un fichero y
>   crearse.

Pasa que solo escribe la ultima palabra en el fichero e ignora las demás. Creo que me esta sobrescribiendo cada palabra que introduzco. Este es el código:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parte1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String palabra;     
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.print("Introduce una palabra (SALIR para salir): ");
            palabra = sc.nextLine();

            EscribirFichero(palabra);

        }while(!palabra.equals("SALIR"));

        System.out.println("Fichero creado");
        sc.close();

    }//FIN MAIN.


    public static void EscribirFichero(String palabra) throws IOException {

        FileWriter fichero = null;
        BufferedWriter buffer = null;

        try {

            fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Parte1.txt");
            buffer = new BufferedWriter(fichero);                                   

            buffer.write(palabra);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado. Cambia la ruta");
        }

        if(palabra.equalsIgnoreCase("salir")) {

            buffer.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, usa [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#targetText=Class%20BufferedWriter&targetText=Writes%20text%20to%20a%20character,large%20enough%20for%20most%20purposes.), saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe principalmente a que en cada ocasión que intentas escribir en el archivo, creas un nuevo `FileWriter` , esta clase por cierto no permite el modo "append" (si no usas Java 11) para poder agregar más información.

En este caso me parece que lo adecuado sería usar [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#targetText=Class%20BufferedWriter&targetText=Writes%20text%20to%20a%20character,large%20enough%20for%20most%20purposes.) para habilitar el archivo en modo "append" y poder agregar siempre más contenido en el archivo.

Ejemplo:

```
 public static void EscribirFichero(String palabra) throws IOException {

     String ruta = "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Parte1.txt";
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ruta, true)); 
     writer.newLine();  //nueva linea!
     writer.write(palabra); //Escribe palabra
     writer.close();  //Cierra BufferedWriter 

 }
```

---

En otro caso puedes usar [FileWriter y habilitar el modo "append" para agregar información pero usando Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset,boolean)) como indica @gbianchi

```
fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Parte1.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas haciendo casi todo correcto. No es que esta sobreescribiendo cada palabra. Es que simplemente estas abriendo y cerrando el archivo por cada palabra. Pero nunca le decis que vas a agregar datos al archivo.

Esa funcion por defecto empieza a escribir siempre al principio del archivo. Y vos queres (siguiendo tu logica) que escriba al final. Entonces, lo que necesitas es otra version de FileWriter

La que necesitas tiene esta firma [public FileWriter(File file,
          boolean append)
           throws IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))

Lo que tenes que hacer, es simplemente dentro del metodo EscribirFichero, reemplazar la forma de abrir el archivo por

```
fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Parte1.txt", true);
```

Ojo, que esto te lleva a otro problema. Si el archivo existe al iniciar tu programa, va a escribir al final del archivo que ya existia....

Asi que ahora tenes otro problema que resolver ;)

---

Tu otro problema es toda la funcion que escribe. abris un archivo, abris un buffer para guardar en el archivo.. pero nunca haces un flush (un volcado) de su contenido. Segun la documentacion, cuando haces write se pasa inmediatamente, pero por lo que vos decis, no estaria haciendo eso.

Te recomendaria hacer varias cosas...

O tenes una funcion que abra el archivo, otra que lo cierre, y otra que escriba solamente..

O en la funcion que tenes, haces siempre `buffer.close();` porque al fin y al cabo estas siempre abriendo el archivo.

Es mas, cuando el usuario escribe salir, ni siquiera tendrias que entrar en esta función.

Comment: Buenas gbianchi. Esto lo he probado también pero me genera el mismo problema. Cuando escribo "SALIR" para finalizar el programa, veo el archivo y solo esta escrito: SALIR. Con y sin el `true` me pasa lo mismo.

Comment: @Youshiro ahora edito, tenes otro problema mas, no me habia dado cuenta... Igual, si probaste esto, es importante que lo pongas en la pregunta!

Comment: Cierto, fallo mio. Perdona :S

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
    *Muy bien, tenes un detalle;
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String palabra;     
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {

            System.out.print("Introduce una palabra (SALIR para salir): ");
            palabra = sc.nextLine();

            try {
                EscribirFichero(palabra);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }while(!palabra.equals("SALIR"));

        System.out.println("Fichero creado");
        sc.close();

    }//FIN MAIN.


    public static void EscribirFichero(String palabra) throws IOException {

        FileWriter fichero = null;
        BufferedWriter buffer = null;

        try {
            //El constructor de FileWriter(ruta, append);
            //Si append = true entonces escribe al final del archivo.
            //Si no al principio.
            fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Parte1.txt",true);
            buffer = new BufferedWriter(fichero);                                   
            //A cada palabra que agregas lo cerras, de esa forma lo guarda.
            //Cuando vuelve a entrar, lo abre y te deja el puntero al final.
            //el if lo puse para que no quede guardado SALIR en el archivo.
            if(!palabra.equals("SALIR")) {
            buffer.write(palabra);
            buffer.close();
           }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado. Cambia la ruta");
        }


    }
    /*
    * Otra forma, un poco mas prolija
    */
        if(!palabra.equals("SALIR")) {
            buffer.write(palabra);
            //flush() lo guarda sin cerrar el archivo 
            buffer.flush();



           }else
            //Si es igual a salir lo cierra; 
               buffer.close();
```

Comment: Hola Sergio, gracias por tu contribución, veo que tienes una explicación dentro del código, regularmente las respuestas que son únicamente código se consideran como de "baja calidad", como recomendación, sería bueno que agregaras la explicación fuera del código, revisa otras respuestas en el sitio, saludos.